# Django admin interface

Tags: python, django

Делал примеры по книжке. Создавал шаблон с простенькой html страницей, где есть текст и картинка

[image: html страница шаблона]

как бы я не ссылался на админ интерфейс http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ все равно перенаправляет меня на шаблон html не пойму что делать. Уже в папке проекта менял файл urls.py  писал вместо пустых кавычек     "admin/"

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include
from rango import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
url(r'admin/', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'', include('rango.urls')),
# above maps any URLs starting
# with rango/ to be handled by
# the rango application
url(r'admin/', admin.site.urls),]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Ну так у вас url адрес 'admin/' два раза определяется. Уберите строку url(r'admin/', views.index, name='index'),

Comment: Хм...и правда помогло, спасибо